# Using a backbone.d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't seem to get any import to work when the module isn't defined as a string. What is going on?

*test.ts*

```
import b = module('Backbone')
```

**Does not work**:
*backbone.d.ts*

```
declare module Backbone {

    export class Events {
    ...
```

**Works**: 
*backbone.d.ts*

```
declare module "Backbone" {

    export class Events {
    ...
```

***Edit 1***:

FYI From [10.1.4](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267121)

> An AmbientModuleIdentification with a StringLiteral declares an external module. This type of declaration is permitted only in the global module. The StringLiteral must specify a top-level external module name. Relative external module names are not permitted

I don't understand how it's useful to *not* specify it as the string literal format as found [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) and [here](http://gh.codehum.com/sekistner/backbone.d.ts). It works if you use `///<reference...` without a string literal module but I'm trying to generate AMD modules that depend on these libraries so I need the import to work. Am I the minority and I have to go and modify each *.d.ts* to be the string literal version?

***Edit 2***:

Declaring a module using a string literal requires that your import is an exact match if that string literal. You can no longer use relative or absolute paths to the location of this module/module definition even if it is not located in the same directory as the file trying to import it. This makes it that a `///<reference` and an import are required but produces a module with `tsc --module AMD` that was exactly looking for (path to module is as dictated by the module string literal `"Backbone"`).

For example.

```
+- dep/
   |- backbone.d.ts
|- test.ts
```

*backbone.d.ts*:

```
declare module "Backbone" {
    export class Events {
```

**Works**: *test.ts*:

```
///<reference path="../dep/backbone.d.ts" />
import b = module('Backbone')

// generates
// define(["require", "exports", 'Backbone']
```

**Does not work**: *test.ts*:

```
import b = module('./dep/Backbone')
```

*Note that this works as well...*

```
declare module "libs/Backbone" {
...
///<reference path="dep/backbone.d.ts" />
import b = module('libs/Backbone')
...
// generates
define(["require", "exports", 'libs/Backbone']
```

Comment: I'm really curious to get a good explanation for that one as well. I filed an [issue](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/231) at codeplex a few weeks back that was on a similar topic. The issue was closed and the comment says it's got something to do with the difference between internal and external modules and that they hope to improve their documentation on that soon...

Comment: You might want to look at my edit 2 findings

Comment: Interesting. I'm still curious as to why many declarations don't use the string literal format.

Comment: @ryan If modify `backbone.d.ts` as `declare module "Backbone" {...` then I get error at `function noConflict(): Backbone;` in the backbone.d.ts saying `'Backbone' does not exist in current scope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:

```
declare module Backbone {
```

It means you have already a module which is in the global scope (so you can immeadiately use it, no import is required). But when you write this:

```
declare module "Backbone" {
```

It means you specify how the imported module (import ... = module("...")) will look.

Comment: I updated my question, if you have any additional thoughts please share